# How to avoid/bypass/ignore a #N/A #NV Error in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, error-handling, google-sheets-formula

I need help creating a formula! I want the formula if it contains a #NV error, to ignore the #NV error. Instead, a value should be output, even if there is a #NV error. Do you have any idea how this could work? When a wrong value is inserted in to the Assignment list, there is an #NV error. How can I ignore it?

`=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(ARRAYFORMULA(SUMME(WENN(ODER((WENN($B$2="dontcare",1,(Assignment!$E$3:$E$577=$B$2))),(WENN($B$3="dontcare",1,(Assignment!$E$3:$E$577=$B$3))),(WENN($B$4="dontcare",1,(Assignment!$E$3:$E$577=$B$4))),(WENN($B$5="dontcare",1,(Assignment!$E$3:$E$577=$B$5))),(WENN($B$6="dontcare",1,(Assignment!$E$3:$E$577=$B$6))))*(WENN($B$7="dontcare",1,(Assignment!$F$3:$F$577=$B$7)))*(WENN($B$8="dontcare",1,(Assignment!$B$3:$F$577=$B$8))),(Assignment!G$3:G$577)))), 1, 1)`

Comment: can you share your sample sheet ?

Comment: @hardy includes sensitive data, not possible

Answer (score 1):

wrap your formula in `IFERROR`

```
IFERROR(your-formula-here; "value if error here")
```

Comment: in the moment it looks like this: Will Iferror work here? When a wrong value is inserted in to the Assignment list -> #NV ```=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(ARRAYFORMULA(SUMME(WENN(ODER((WENN($B$2="dontcare",1,(Assignment!$E$3:$E$577=$B$2))),(WENN($B$3="dontcare",1,(Assignment!$E$3:$E$577=$B$3))),(WENN($B$4="dontcare",1,(Assignment!$E$3:$E$577=$B$4))),(WENN($B$5="dontcare",1,(Assignment!$E$3:$E$577=$B$5))),(WENN($B$6="dontcare",1,(Assignment!$E$3:$E$577=$B$6))))*(WENN($B$7="dontcare",1,(Assignment!$F$3:$F$577=$B$7)))*(WENN($B$8="dontcare",1,(Assignment!$B$3:$F$577=$B$8))),(Assignment!G$3:G$577)))), 1, 1)```

Comment: when I put ur code, it says value if error, but there could be for example a 2.0 in this field, and it should say the number 2.0 then and not value if error here. YOu understand what I mean?

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: not possible, includes sensitive data :( hope you can still help me

Comment: try: `=IFERROR(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(ARRAYFORMULA(SUMME(WENN(ODER((WENN($B$2="dontcare",1,(Assignment!$E$3:$E$577=$B$2))),(WENN($B$3="dontcare",1,(Assignment!$E$3:$E$577=$B$3))),(WENN($B$4="dontcare",1,(Assignment!$E$3:$E$577=$B$4))),(WENN($B$5="dontcare",1,(Assignment!$E$3:$E$577=$B$5))),(WENN($B$6="dontcare",1,(Assignment!$E$3:$E$577=$B$6))))*(WENN($B$7="dontcare",1,(Assignment!$F$3:$F$577=$B$7)))*(WENN($B$8="dontcare",1,(Assignment!$B$3:$F$577=$B$8))),(Assignment!G$3:G$577)))), 1, 1), "2.0")`

Comment: ok works, but the numbers can change, from 2.0 to 1.2 or 0.3 and so on, how can I catch that?

Comment: Already a big thx @player0!  So the numbers can change from 0.0 to a range of 5.0 (0.0 - 5.0)! if you could give me a sloution for that problem, that would be incredible! :)

Comment: Please describe in your answer, what was the problem, and how will this snippet solve it, to help others understand this answer

Comment: @greenster10 change based on what? randomly?

Comment: change based on demands, which can change from month to month

Comment: this case is till not solved! The values can change randomly yes

Comment: @FZs i still need your help!

Comment: if you could share a copy of your sheet with fake data I am sure I can solve it

Comment: that is unfortunately not possible... don't you have any idea?